# HMAC Encoding in R vs Python

Tags: python, r, hmac

I am trying to create a token for an API call in R.  I have example code and output in Python, but I am unable to replicate in R.  I know little to nothing about encoding, decoding, etc.  Hoping someone can shed some light on what I can do to make these outputs match.  Here is a toy example.

R Code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(digest)

api_key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789=="
decoded_api_key = base64Decode(api_key)
hmac_binary = hmac(decoded_api_key, "MySpecialString", "sha512")
hmac_encoded = base64Encode(digest(hmac_binary))
print(as.character(hmac_encoded))
# ZmZjZDBlMjkyNzg3NDNmYWM1ZDcyNjVkNmY4ZmM1OGQ=
```

Python:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

api_key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789=="
decoded_api_key = base64.b64decode(api_key)
hmac_binary = hmac.new(decoded_api_key, "MySpecialString", hashlib.sha512)
hmac_encoded = base64.b64encode(hmac_binary.digest())
print(hmac_encoded)
# MduxNfXVkwcOtCpBWJEl96S43boYVYTtHb4waR21ARCMo6iokKuxbwEJMTkuytbrCOxvBqKCYiaZiV/AyHTEcw==
```

The answers I obtain are given at the end of the code blocks. Clearly they don't match.  I'd like someone to help me change my R code to match the Python output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `digest()` function in R doesn't do the same thing as the `.digest()` method in python. It doesn't extract the value, it computes a new digest for whatever you pass in. Also the `hmac` function will by default return a string with the bytes in it, but you want to base64 encode the actual bytes so you need to make sure to request the raw values. Finally, a base64 string should have a multiple of 4 characters in the string. The extra padding seems to return a different value. So this should give the same value as the python code

```
api_key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789="
decoded_api_key = base64Decode(api_key)
hmac_binary = hmac(decoded_api_key, "MySpecialString", "sha512", raw=TRUE)
hmac_encoded = base64Encode(hmac_binary)
print(as.character(hmac_encoded))
# [1] "MduxNfXVkwcOtCpBWJEl96S43boYVYTtHb4waR21ARCMo6iokKuxbwEJMTkuytbrCOxvBqKCYiaZiV/AyHTEcw=="
```